# Android - Display iFrame video in Html.FromHTML

Tags: android, html, json, iframe

I want to create a News App and now, my app displays posts from Json with Html Parser.

I use the `Html.FromHtml()` for display text and pictures but I want to display video too.

I want to know if it is possible to display video in TextView with  `Html.FromHtml()` of only with a Webview.

This is my code:

```
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(json_data.getString("contenu"), this, null);
description_projet.setText(spanned);
```

And the Json in "contenu":

```
<p>Ideoque fertur neminem aliquando ob haec vel similia<\/p>\r\n\r\n
<p><iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/ifOlLcKM7gk\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen><\/iframe><\/p>\r\n\r\n
<p>Ideoque fertur neminem aliquando ob haec vel similia poenae addictum oblato de more elogio revocari iussisse, quod inexorabiles quoque principes factitarunt. et exitiale hoc vitium, quod in aliis non numquam intepescit, in illo aetatis progressu effervescebat, obstinatum eius propositum accendente adulatorum cohorte.<\/p>\r\n
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, its not possible. check [HTML Tags Supported By TextView](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)  and [HTML in TextViews](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html)

Only WebView or custom/native way (e.g.`VideoView`)

Comment: How the majority of news applications do to display videos ? With WebView ? Edit: Thanks !

Comment: Video streaming, lot of ways and libs, e.g. for above `VideoView` there is `videoView.setVideoURI(videoURI);` method. With WebView it's difficult do fit into different hardware (screens), "handle" frame with rotation, e.t.c